# iOS EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=1 Core Data

Tags: ios

I have an issue with core data. In view controller method `viewDidLoad` I'm requesting:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [databaseManagementService selectUsers]);
```

After request I get Error:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x80945a35)
```

Can anyone help me to deal with this issue? My code:

```
- (NSArray *)selectUsers
{
    NSMutableArray *userObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSArray *userManagedObjects = [self queryUsers];

    if (userManagedObjects)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < userManagedObjects.count; i++)
        {
            TaskManagerUser *userObject = [[TaskManagerUser alloc] init];
            User *userManagedObject = userManagedObjects[i];

            userObject.id = userManagedObject.id;
            userObject.name = userManagedObject.name;
            userObject.surname = userManagedObject.surname;

            userObject.counterValue = userManagedObject.counterValue;
            userObject.gpsLog = userManagedObject.gpsLog;
            userObject.material = userManagedObject.material;
            userObject.taskNew = userManagedObject.newTask;
            userObject.taskAssignNew = userManagedObject.newTaskAssign;
            userObject.taskPictureNew = userManagedObject.newTaskPicture;
            userObject.taskAction = userManagedObject.taskAction;
            userObject.taskPicture = userManagedObject.taskPicture;

            [userObjects addObject:userObject];
        }
    }

    else
    {
        return nil;
    }

    return userObjects;
}
```

I have tried to debug, and in the return line userObjects looks fine... Can anyone help me please?

queryUsers:

```
- (NSArray *)queryUsers
{
    NSArray *usersManagedObjectsList = [self queryEntitiesForName:entityUser withPredicate:nil];
    if (usersManagedObjectsList != nil && usersManagedObjectsList.count > 0)
    {
        return usersManagedObjectsList;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

also:

```
- (NSArray *)queryEntitiesForName:(NSString *)name withPredicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate
{
    NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:name inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entityDescription];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];
    [request setIncludesSubentities:YES];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *array = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    if (array == nil)
    {
        TaskManagerAlertErrorService *taskManagerAlertErrorService = [[TaskManagerAlertErrorService alloc] init];

        [taskManagerAlertErrorService alertErrorWithTitle:JSONDatabaseManagementServiceErrorTitle andMessage:JSONDatabaseManagementServiceErrorMessage andCancelButtonTitle:JSONDatabaseManagementServiceErrorCancelButtonTitle];
    }
    return array;
}
```

Also, there is no stack trace in console...

Comment: Please post the stacktrace.

Comment: And the  [self queryUsers method

Comment: Here you go. Any suggestions how to fix it now?

Comment: If you said you debugged and that the return line is fine, I am suspecting that your error might come from elsewhere? Add exception breakpoints in xcode to see where the error is coming from

Comment: Yes, I have been trying to do it for a long time without any success...

Comment: I have noticed one thing. Elements id, name, surname are managed object attributes. Other attributes are just relations. When I comment relations, all works fine. How should I pass relations?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I found an answer! The error was here:

```
userObject.taskNew = userManagedObject.newTask;
userObject.taskAssignNew = userManagedObject.newTaskAssign;
userObject.taskPictureNew = userManagedObject.newTaskPicture;
```

Managed Object  attributes can't start with "new".

```
userObject.taskNew = userManagedObject.taskNew;
userObject.taskAssignNew = userManagedObject.taskAssignNew;
userObject.taskPictureNew = userManagedObject.taskPictureNew;
```

Works perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Is this even valid:

```
userObjects[i] = userObject;
```

?

How does the array know to allocate enough memory to assign an object at index "i"?

I would suggest using:

```
[userObjects addObject:userObject];
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you specified that you have a problem using CoreData I guess that TaskUserManager is a subclass of **NSManagedObject**?

If so then your error is here:

```
TaskManagerUser *userObject = [[TaskManagerUser alloc] init];
```

You cannot alloc CoreData entities with init. You need to use your object context and use the following line:

```
[objectContext insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"TaskUserManager"]
```

Comment: Actually no. TaskManagerUser is a subclass of NSObject. Class User is a subclass of NSManagedObject...